# drupal webform sliding radio button

Tags: webforms, javascript

I m trying to build a form that has questions with radio button answers when someone clicks on a radio button the next question comes up and it should have a next and prev button is there any php code i need to put in? or will it be just jquery as i m very new to php and javascript

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module and read [this](http://drupal.org/node/324779).

The full documentation is at http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/webform.

You can achieve the conditional field with [Webform Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional).

> This modules enhances the existing Conditional Rules of the Webform
>   Module. It adds the ability to make components dependent on select
>   components(i.e. listboxes, radio buttons, and checkboxes) that appear
>   on the same page.

Here's a youtube video [Screencast demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uxfqJr6K6U).

> Webform already has support for conditional fields on multi-page
>   forms. For example Field C on Page 2 can be dependent on Field A on
>   Page 1. This module adds the ability to have conditional fields on the
>   same page. This module adds the ability to have Field B on page 1 be
>   dependent on Field A also on Page 1.

Check the version of the Webform module; you may have it already.

Comment: i have done that but what i want is when someone clicks on a radio button the next question slide out instead of clicking next page button.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at https://drupal.org/project/webform_ajax_page it renders all pages at once and uses AJAX to go to the next page, you might be able to add a sliding effect by hooking into the javascript

Answer (score 0):

The conditional field module will let you set conditions for a field to appear or not.

For example if the question is do you have a cat? Then fields like:

Siamese
Stray
Kitten

And if you click on the radio button dog:

German Shepperd
Bulldog
Pitbll

Ect...

http://drupal.org/node/1704126 does this